# GCC return address of calling function in ARM architecture

Tags: c, gcc, stack, arm

I'm curious why `__builtin_return_address()` doesn't supports other arguments than 0 in ARM ?
It's a problem that somehow you can't deduce calling function address from the stack of ARM ? 
Or something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this post <http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/05/pre-mortem-backtracing.html>,

> Also on some architectures, including my beloved MIPS, only `__builtin_return_address(0)` works. MIPS has no frame pointer, making it difficult to walk back up the stack. Frame 0 can use the return address register directly.
>   If ARM also does not have a frame pointer, this would explain the limitation.

See also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html.

Comment: On the ARM, the return address is passed in register `R14`, and it is the duty of the callee to save it when calling another function. So even with a frame pointer, there is no guarantee that the return address is ever stored on the stack.

Comment: Indeed, when the return address is callee-saved rather than saved on the stack by the call instruction, it's impossible in general to find it. There should be a way using dwarf2 unwind/debugging data, but that would require `__builtin_return_address` to be a call to a heavy weight unwind library call rather than a trivial builtin...

Comment: BTW, I solved this stack tracing problem on ARM by using [-finstrument-functions](http://gcc.activeventure.org/Code-Gen-Options.html) which are called on every function entry/exit. There is overhead of course, but it is acceptable for me. (And there is  `no_instrument_function` attribute where max speed of call is required...)

Answer (score 4):

Backtrace on ARM *is* hard. The Glibc `backtrace` function does work these days, but you need an up to date compiler/glibc, and you need to have built everything with -funwind-tables. GDB also has trouble without debug info.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning -funwind-tables!  My backtraces on ARM were always depth 1 until I enabled this compiler flag. Using GCC 4.3.2.